# Swap the position of map item

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, indexing, position, treemap

How can I swap an item's order in a `TreeMap` in Kotlin? Something like `Collections.swap()` but on a map, not on a list. Like swapping an item's position with another item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TreeMap is a self-sorting collection, so you can't swap elements. The map elements gets sorted in a tree according to their natural ordering (if they implement `Comparable` interface) or according to a custom `Comparator` that you need to provide to the map.

More info in the JavaDoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

If arbitrary ordering (and/or re-ordering) is important to you, you may want to consider other kinds of collections, like `List` for example, or a combination of multiple collections.

Comment: LinkedHashMap would be appropriate.

Comment: @Tenfour04 a `LinkedHashMap` can operate in insert-order (or access-order, but I don't think this case is suitable), which means to swap 2 elements keeping all the others in the same position you'd need to remove all elements from the last one till the first index you want to swap, and the re-insert all the elements in the desired order (or create a brand new list altogether). This could be a solution, depending on the use case there could be better ways of dealing with the problem.